# MySql syntax error on procedure parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write a simple procedure but am encountering a syntax error at the first parameter. As best I can tell I'm following the syntax of [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) correctly.

I am limited to accessing my database with phpMyAdmin. Here is the create script I'm trying to run:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS product_index_swap/
CREATE PROCEDURE product_index_swap (@id INT, @oldIndex INT, @newIndex INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @swapID;
    SET @swapID = (SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE `order_index` = @newIndex LIMIT 1);
    UPDATE `products` SET `order_index` = (CASE WHEN `id` = @id THEN @newIndex
                                                WHEN `id` = @swapID THEN @oldIndex END)
    WHERE `id` IN (@id, @swapID);
END
```

I am using the option on phpMyAdmin to change the delimiter to /.

I receive a syntax error "near '`@id INT, @oldIndex INT....`". I thought I may encounter more delimiter errors since I'm not entirely clear on the scope of them. I believe if that was the problem the error would be on a new line in the procedure when it failed to understand a semicolon, not at the parameters declaration.

Comment: Just remove `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Microsoft SQL Server convention of putting `@` before all the parameters and local variables. MySQL doesn't do this.

In MySQL syntax, procedure parameters have no sigil.

Also parameters are typically declared `IN` or `OUT` or `INOUT`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE product_index_swap (IN id INT, IN oldIndex INT, IN newIndex INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE swapID;
    ...
```

MySQL variables that have the `@` sigil are *session variables*.

See also:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the @var variables are session level variables.

Use normal variables without the @ and make sure you do not have conflict with column names:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE product_index_swap (in_id INT, in_oldIndex INT, in_newIndex INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_swapID int;

    SELECT id into v_swapID
    FROM product 
    WHERE order_index = in_newIndex 
    LIMIT 1;

    UPDATE products
    SET order_index = CASE WHEN id = in_id THEN in_newIndex
                           WHEN id = v_swapID THEN in_oldIndex 
                      END
    WHERE id IN (in_id, v_swapID);
END
```