# Mysql stored procedure gives unknown column error when executed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a small stored procedure to store redmine issue and timelog entries in my private redmine. The procedure is stored, but when I call it, it gives `SQL error (1054): Unknown column 'uid' in 'field list'` error.
The column that the error message mention is exists, the type matches.

Rewrite code, redeploy db

When the second insert removed from SP, it works great.

```
delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE if exists redmine.insert_fingerprint_workday_and_hour $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `insert_fingerprint_workday_and_hour`(
    IN `userid` INT(11) )
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''

BEGIN

set @uid=userid;

INSERT INTO issues (
tracker_id,
project_id,
subject,
description,
due_date,
category_id,
status_id,
assigned_to_id,
priority_id,
fixed_version_id,
author_id,
lock_version,
created_on,
updated_on,
start_date,
done_ratio,
estimated_hours,
parent_id,
root_id,
lft,
rgt,
is_private,
closed_on ) 
 VALUES
(
  "4",                      -- tracker id
  "1",                          -- project id
  "teszt subject",      -- subject  
  "teszt description",  -- description 
  NULL,                         -- due_date
  NULL,                         -- category_id
  "7",                          -- status id
  uid,              -- assigned_to_id
  "2",                          -- priority_id
  NULL,                     -- fixed_version_id
  uid,                  --  author_id
  "0",                          -- lock_version
  NOW(),                    -- created_on
  NOW(),                        -- updated_on
  date(now()),              -- start_date
  "0",                      -- done_ratio
  NULL,                     -- estimated_hours
  NULL,                     -- parent_id
  "1",                      -- root_id
  "1",                      -- lft
  "2",                      -- rgt
  "0",                      -- is_private
  now()                     -- closed_on
  );

  set @ujissue=LAST_INSERT_ID();

  insert into time_entries 
  (project_id,user_id,issue_id,hours,activity_id,spent_on,tyear,tmonth,tweek,created_on,updated_on)
  values
  (
  "1",                      -- project_id
  uid,                  -- user_id
  ujissue,                  -- issue_id
  "8",                      -- hours
  "10",                     -- activity_id
  date(now()),              -- spent_on
  year(now()),              -- tyear
  month(now()),         -- tmonth
  week(now()),              -- tweek
  now(),                        -- created_on
  now()
  );

  END $$

  DELIMITER ;

SQL> CALL redmine.insert_fingerprint_workday_and_hour('7');
/* SQL error (1054): Unknown column 'uid' in 'field list' */
```

The only input is a number, a user_id. The code should add an issue to a project and log 8 workhours. The first insert adds the issue to the project and a second logs the hours.

After hours of debugging I cannot figure out what can be the problem.

All advice is welcome!

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Please provide a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the schema of your table.

Comment: `uid` is not the same as `@uid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, variables with the `@` sigil are session variables, not local variables. Session variables are different from local variables, even if they have the same name other than the `@` sigil.

See also a few of my past answers on this:

- ["@" symbol in stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323538/symbol-in-stored-procedure/15323806#15323806)
- [MySql syntax error on procedure parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718975/mysql-syntax-error-on-procedure-parameter/47719103#47719103)
- [Stored Procedure Null Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076191/stored-procedure-null-error/49076419#49076419)

Comment: Thank you, I have rewritten my code based on your clear instructions, now its working.